# Should dropping out of a PhD program be treated the same way as quitting a regular, industry job?

Tags: phd, job, industry, quitting

I personally see no practical difference between dropping out of a PhD program and quitting a regular job, at least considering the way PhDs work in the US, especially in STEM fields, but I'm sure many people will disagree. Please let me elaborate why I think that way, and let me know if I'm being too naive or missing an important difference. I really want to see a difference, but so far I can't find any meaningful one.

At least in the US, PhD students are often employees of the university, they hold a research assistant position, get paid a salary and declare it as taxable income. Most people I've talked with in academia agree that the main point of doing a PhD is working on your own research rather than taking classes, which should just be a complement. That sounds pretty much like what you do at a regular job than what you do in a master's or undergrad degree; you have a main project to work on, and maybe some ocasional training sessions that might be useful for your work. Some people like to point out that dropping out of a PhD program has some sort of stigma attached to it because it means that you couldn't finish something you began. However, I see no difference between that situation and quitting a regular job where you had a long-term project that you realized was going nowhere, had no future or was needlessly stressful, and you decided not to waste your time trying to finish it and find something better. My view is that if you leave a PhD program with no degree, but you worked for some years as a research assistant, you can still write it down in your resume as a research assistant position you had at the university, so it's pretty much just another job for practical purposes, I don't understand why the fact that you didn't get the degree is such a big deal for some people.

Something I should emphasize is that I'm biased in my thinking towards STEM fields and people who enter PhD programs, but have no intention to stay in academia. If one wants to become a professor, dropping out of a PhD program is obviously a big deal, since it's often a requirement, but I'm talking about people who do PhDs mainly to get better jobs in industry. I know some will point out that that's probably a bad reason to do a PhD to begin with, but honestly, I've met many PhD students who think that way, especially in computer science and other STEM fields. Regardless, many people also begin a PhD because they are really interested in working on a specific area and that area happens to be developed more in academia than in industry at some point in time (machine learning is a good example), but they don't have any intention of staying in academia and plan to get a job in industry afterwards. Still, they might get disappointed about the area or the environment along the way, the same way one might serious negative aspects of what seemed at first as an interesting job.

I'm especially interested in reading people who disagree with any of the specific points I mentioned before and why they are not valid analogies between dropping out of a PhD program and quitting a job. If this looks more like an open-ended discussion rather than an appropriate question for this site, feel free to put it on hold, but I'd appreciate if you can point me to a more appropriate site where this kind of discussion can take place. This site is the only one I know where well-informed academics congregate.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: "main point of doing a PhD is working on your own research rather than taking classes, which should just be a complement." After I got my BSc, I went into industry, and that sounds nothing like what I've seen in 10 years in industry. Very few people get paid to do research in industry - for the most part, you have to be productive and revenue generating (or supporting those who are revenue generating.)

Comment: On “people entering a PhD program without intention to stay in the academia”: There are many PhD programs, or specific situations of a student in some phd program, that by itself doesn’t have any chance to lead to an decent academic position. I’m not counting going to a community college or going to anywhere just for teaching when one’s goal is to research. People just have no hope to expect an academic future.

Answer (score 7):

This answer addresses the idea that the work a PhD student does is just like work at another job, and therefore quitting the jobs should be viewed the same. (My answer suggests that it should be unusual for people to enroll and then quit without there being a serious problem, and also that potentially elements of society might place stigma on that action to keep people from wasting educational resources.) There also seems to be an indication in the question that people should be free to casually start positions as Ph.D. students without the intention to finish the degree. (I may be overstating the poster's view, but that extreme version is what I address below.)

I believe that for an individual, leaving a program or leaving academia can be the right choice for all involved, and that work as a graduate student is valid work experience to list on a resume. However, it is harmful in the long term if people enter graduate school without the intention of completing the degree.

---

A huge part of the compensation for being a PhD student is funding one's classes, training, library access, access to lab materials, potentially travel funding, and access to smart peers and smart professors. It costs a lot to create a learning and research environment.

For instance, a postdoc working a similar job in a lab will get paid more; partly because they need less supervision and training, have more experience, and have more responsibility, but also because the professor does not have to fund the tuition and student benefits for that postdoc. And a professional lab worker should be paid even more.

**If, as you say, being a PhD student is just another job**, then people who do not value all of the parts that support academic success could value those things at zero and realize **they are getting a very poor wage.** They could work at a private lab for the same work--but without the support for learning and autonomous research--and get paid much more for the same style of tasks.

Again, it costs a lot to create a learning and research environment, and **universities are investing in their students' success**. Hoxby has a model of university funding that likens university founders (and later donors) to venture capitalists investing in human capital and in research: http://www.nber.org/papers/w18626.

As Hoxby writes: "Because some of the students' returns will presumably be social, the obligation on them can be multifaceted.  Those who earn private returns on their human capital can be asked for gifts in the form of money. Others could be asked for gifts in the form of expertise. Others could be asked to use their political influence to sure that the university is treated well by the government.  And so on." [Hoxby 2012, p. 19](http://www.nber.org/papers/w18626.pdf)

If people are taking Ph.D. positions as mere jobs, they are less likely to fully contribute to the educational environment, less likely to take full advantage of the costly investment in their educational environment, and less likely to give back to the institution to help it sustain itself.

---

**TL;DR: It is extremely short-sighted to think that students are merely workers. It is to academia's detriment if students, professors, schools, and governments act as if they are.**

(These models and my thinking are largely based on the U.S. system, which the poster addressed. I would be interested in thoughts on how this compares to other funding models.)

---

Note: I do not intend this answer to say that grad students are or are not employees for the purposes of unionization or other purposes. However, I believe this account of why schools fund tuition for advanced students as an uncertain investment helps us understand why the rebated tuition should not be taxed as regular income (as a recent US tax plan suggested doing).

Answer (score 3):

I've always seen a PhD pursuit as a **chance**. An opportunity, for which one'd be willing to surrender, to adapt to, or at least to bear with some of the below issues.

I strongly oppose the feelings of a PhD program as a regular job. Let's look at some properties.

Negative:

- It's never* just a 9-to-5 job. You more or less dedicate a period in your life to research.
- It's not competitive by salary.
- You are still at campus with all advantages and drawbacks it brings.

Positive:

- It's a unique experience, as quite few students would land in a R&D division right after school.
- You get a title for life and, possibly, a ticket to academia if you succeed.

*: Some can manage to pull 9-to-5 job at research. Some can commit to this. Many fail, so the success stories might be a somewhat survivors' paradox. I've seen enough reputable researchers who claim that research is never 9-to-5.

Disclaimer: I have a PhD.

Comment: Whenever people mention “the title” as a reason for why the injustice in the phd pursuing is worth to endure, I’d think this is just a pyramidal scam. They sell the title which is worth nothing unless referrals continue to join and value it.

Comment: At least in Germany, the title is somewhat of importance. That's why many politicians are getting it.

Comment: I’m talking about WHY the titles are important,  not WHETHER they are. Pyramidal scam means people think the title is important and make others think so because they were cheated into the investment, not because the missing of the title necessarily says anything about one’s abilities. Of course, I’ve heard about the rigidity of German phd requirement so it might be only for the US academia. Many industry people actually have better quality of work than the phds or even professors from less ideal schools. Some professors work really an indecent way just to thread jacking with papers

Answer (score 2):

As a student who left a PhD program, I agree overall but disagree on some specifics. We both agree that there should be less stigma around dropping out, that there are very understandable reasons for doing so, and that grad students have more in common with employees than most academics find it convenient to believe. Depending on the work and the time span, companies can invest a significant amount of time and money in a person too. That person can become an integral part of that business, especially if it is a small one, and yet people are not judged for leaving the same way.

However, I think quitting partway through a program, as I did, *is* a bad sign. I would not judge someone personally for it, given my experience, but I might harbor some doubt about them professionally, and I understand why someone evaluating me as a job candidate might think that way.

There are such large personal and financial costs to PhD programs that quitting seems odd. You forego a decent wage, sign away your 20s to school, and very likely uproot yourself to live in some small college town for the next 5-7 years away from everybody you know. Life is placed on hold. After all that it takes to get in, turning away signals uncertainty and a lack of direction.

Like your examples show, leaving can indeed be a measured, calculated decision, but someone would need to explain that this is the case; I would not assume it. I have some explaining to do when I interview, and that's alright. The consequences of my decision are on me. I have to own them.

Going back to the personal, dropping out also feels a lot different. The relationship you have with your advisor can skate the edge between boss and mentor and, very commonly, between colleague and friend. I feel guilty for abandoning my advisor in a way that I simply wouldn't with a boss. I miss my advisor. I miss the other professors in my department. I feel like I disappointed all of them, and I do regret that I wasted their time, but hindsight is 20/20. If I knew the outcome of my grad school experience ahead of time, I certainly would not have gone.

Comment: How do you suppose the relationship between an advisor and a phd student is like that? That’s probably the most likely place for an abusive relationship.

Answer (score 1):

There is one significant difference between PhD positions and jobs: in many cases, a PhD who leaves can get a master’s degree instead of the PhD, depending on the program. However, in some countries, the PhD program is research-only, and the difference between leaving a PhD and leaving a job are similar.